# Asp.net mvc3: How to pull data from database and fill view model in one goal?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to pull the data from DB and fill the view model, is there any better way to do this? 
Currently I'm doing something like this.

```
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
var recentBill = context.Money.Take(10);
foreach (var r in recnetBill)
{
    vm.lst.Add(r);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   IEnumerable<Money> lst { get; set; }
   // other properties
}
```

Just do this:

```
public ActionResult GetMonies()
{
   var monies = context.Money
                      .Take(10)
                      .ToList();

   var model = new ViewModel { lst = monies };

   return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable` has the `ToList()` function which returns a list of said type.

```
vm.lst = context.Money.Take(10).ToList(); // returns a List<Money>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to prevent possibility of changing ViewModel.lst, i.e. lst's type should be IEnumerable instead of List/IList (of course if your further code doesn't require List functionality).

Furthermore, I suppose you don't modify lst reference, so you could remove setter and initialize lst via constructor.

```
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ViewModel(IEnumerable<Money> lst)
        {
            this._lst = lst;
        }

        private readonly IEnumerable<Money> _lst;
        IEnumerable<Money> Lst 
        { 
            get 
            {
                return this._lst;
            }
        }
        // other properties
    }

    public ActionResult GetMonies()
    {
        var model = new ViewModel(context.Money.Take(10).ToArray());
        return View(model);
    }
```

This approach guarantees that consumers of your code will not modify your ViewModel.Lst accidentally.